# In F# is it OK to make a shorthand function to print using %A

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#, f#-interactive

I'm just starting to use F# for the first time, using VSCode and interactive notebooks. I am super annoyed at having to constantly write out

```ml
printfn "%A" something
```

because it kills me inside.

Is it wrong to at the start of every file simply write:

```ml
let print(something) = printfn "%A" something

// then use with

print(4 + 3) // int
print(3.7 + 1.1) //float
print("this is so much better") // text
```

Why the heck isn't this built in?!

Comment: *Why the heck isn't this built in* - there's suggestion to add this function https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/1092

Comment: That’s excellent news. Thanks!

Comment: That thread contained a link to another question with a much better workaround than what I posted above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73416468/hello-printfn-generates-an-error-in-f

Comment: One reason there isn't an easy way to do this already is that the `%A` format specifier uses reflection and can be very slow. You want to avoid it in production code and therefore it shouldn't be easy to do accidentally. While exploring with FSI, it automatically prints the last evaluated option. Interactive notebooks are quite new so they haven't yet been made totally convenient to work with in F#.

Comment: Having said that, they did change `.ToString()` to do `%A` like printing on F# types so you will get a similar effect (not exactly the same) using the built-in `stdout.WriteLine`.

Comment: The language suggestion when implemented may or may not print things other than strings, and if it does it would not use %A formatting, but the simpler `string` formatting, similar to `print(f) $"{4 + 3}"` and not far from what you would get now with `Console.WriteLine`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out to be non trivial to make this built-in. Not because it’s a technical challenge, but because there’s not a single answer to “how to print X”, when the type is generic. Should it use internationalisation or not? Should it work like `ToString`? Should it behave like `%A`, which is slow and has changed between F# versions?

An implementation was made, and then halted, precisely because we didn’t have a definitive answer to these questions. I have an opinion and a preference, but my preference may not be yours. Which is why this isn’t as trivial as we’d like it to be.

That said, it is very common to have a little helper function like you wrote. Perhaps you’d make another one with `%O` (which takes `ToString()` behaviour). I often also make one specific for logging that behaves like `printfn`, but logs it somewhere.

The presence of interpolated strings has made the requirement for such helpers a little less demanding. But sure enough, functions that just dump the contents of a type are still very common.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course, it's ok to do this. Perhaps the easiest is to

```ml
open type System.Console
```

And then use

```ml
WriteLine (4 + 3) // int
WriteLine (3.7 + 1.1) //float
WriteLine "this is so much better" // text
```